# Elasticsearch query based on two values

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to use elasticsearch in order to find documents with a rule based on two doc properties.

Lets say the documents are in the following structure:

```
{
  "customer_payment_timestamp" : 14387930787,
  "customer_delivery_timestamp" : 14387230787,
}
```

and i would like to query these kind of documents and find all documents where ***customer_payment_timestamp*** is greater than ***customer_delivery_timestamp***.

Tried the official documentation, but I couldn't find any relevant example regarding the query itself or a pre-mapped field... is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with a [`script` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-query.html) like this:

```
POST index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": "doc.customer_payment_timestamp.value > doc. customer_delivery_timestamp.value"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note: you need to make sure that [dynamic scripting is enabled](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting)

Comment: Thanks. i get the following error when using this: "reason": {
"type": "script_exception",
"reason": "scripts of type [inline], operation [search] and lang [groovy] are disabled"
}

Comment: It did... Thanks! I guess that dynamic scripting hits the performance, right?

Comment: Yes, it does a little bit. In your case, you should probably create another boolean field `payment_after_delivery` at indexing time that contains that condition and then you'll be able to query that new field with a very simple `term` query

Comment: thought so, is it possible using the mapping file only or should i contaminate my entity?

Comment: You don't have to see this as a "contamination", it's simply helping you search your entities. It's not uncommon to have lots of "helper" fields being indexed in order to make searches faster.